# Concatenate list of lists in a pandas datagram

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a pandas datagram like this. I want to concatenate the nested lists in the pandas cells. I referred the question in [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) which has all possible solutions to do this. I chose to do it with numpy. However, I am getting this error - **lambda row: [np.concatenate(x) for x in row])
ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate**. I don't have enough knowledge in python to solve this on my own. How should I modify my method to properly concatenate these nested lists?

> Datagram

```
[[(ive, searching), (searching, right), (right, word), (word, thank), (thank, breather)], [(i, promise), (promise, wont), (wont, take), (take, help), (help, granted), (granted, fulfil), (fulfil, promise)], [(you, wonderful), (wonderful, blessing), (blessing, time)]]                                                            

[[(free, entry), (entry, 2), (2, wkly), (wkly, comp), (comp, win), (win, fa), (fa, cup), (cup, final), (final, tkts), (tkts, 21st), (21st, may), (may, 2005)], [(text, fa), (fa, 87121), (87121, receive), (receive, entry), (entry, questionstd), (questionstd, txt), (txt, ratetcs), (ratetcs, apply), (apply, 08452810075over18s)]]

[[(nah, dont), (dont, think), (think, go), (go, usf), (usf, life), (life, around), (around, though)]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

[[(even, brother), (brother, like), (like, speak), (speak, me)], [(they, treat), (treat, like), (like, aid), (aid, patent)]]
```

> Concatenation method

```
def toFlatListBigram(fullCorpus):
flatListBigram = fullCorpus['bigrams'].apply(
    lambda row: [np.concatenate(x) for x in row])
return flatListBigram
```

Answer (score 0):

> This worked

```
def toFlatListBigram(fullCorpus):
flatListBigram = fullCorpus['bigrams'].apply(
    lambda row: [item for sublist in row for item in sublist])
return flatListBigram
```